# BasicNameValuePair character escaping

Tags: java, urlencode

I am trying to pass in a string containing both html entities as well as odd characters like trademark and copyright symbols in to the value of a BasicNameValuePair in java.  Right now fails silently when I try to execute it.  Code:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8983");
String test = "<field name=\"description\">Example®&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt; This is a bunch of stuff I would like to post&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;</field>
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stream.body", test));   // HERE is the string
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commit","true"));

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I believe that the "& symbols are causing an issue as they are probably query characters that the URL must deal with separately.  How do I execute this type of string in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out for handling special characters. I think this might help

"Arbitrary text placed in an HTML tag often needs to be altered, to ensure that the resulting HTML remains valid. "
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96